# Basler Pylon 4 SDK and OPENCV 2.4.8, Linux simple viewer

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, computer-vision

I am developing a simple camera viewer to test Basler camera acA1300-30gc. I am working in Ubuntu 14.04 with Basler Pylon 4 and OPENCV version 2.4.8 because I am going to develop a machine vision application and I need to analyze frames on the fly.

Based on [OpenCV Display Image Tutorial](http://opencv-srf.blogspot.it/2013/06/load-display-image.html), Sample Code in Pylon Documentation and [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24101877/basler-pylon-4-sdk-and-opencv-2-4-9-cpylonimage-to-mat) I write the following code.

Code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    Pylon::PylonAutoInitTerm autoInitTerm;
    Mat image(IM_HEIGHT, IM_WIDTH, CV_8UC3);
    CGrabResultPtr ptrGrabResult;

    //namedWindow(WIN_NAME,CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    try {
        CInstantCamera camera( CTlFactory::GetInstance().CreateFirstDevice());
        cout << "Using device " << camera.GetDeviceInfo().GetModelName() << endl;
        camera.StartGrabbing();

        while(camera.IsGrabbing()){
            camera.RetrieveResult( 5000, ptrGrabResult, TimeoutHandling_ThrowException);
            if (ptrGrabResult->GrabSucceeded()){
                    memcpy(image.ptr(),ptrGrabResult->GetBuffer(),ptrGrabResult->GetWidth()*ptrGrabResult->GetHeight());
                    //if(!image.empty())
                    //imshow(WIN_NAME,image);
                    //if(waitKey(30)==27){
                    //      camera.StopGrabbing();
                    //}
            }
        }
    } catch (GenICam::GenericException &e) {
        cerr << "An exception occurred." << endl  << e.GetDescription() << endl;
    }

    //destroyWindow(WIN_NAME);
    return 0;

}
```

I don't know why uncommenting `namedWindow(WIN_NAME,CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);` the camera doesn't grab anymore.

I would be very grateful if some one could help me please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Grab.cpp
/*
Note: Before getting started, Basler recommends reading the Programmer's Guide topic
in the pylon C++ API documentation that gets installed with pylon.
If you are upgrading to a higher major version of pylon, Basler also
strongly recommends reading the Migration topic in the pylon C++ API documentation.

This sample illustrates how to grab and process images using the CInstantCamera class.
The images are grabbed and processed asynchronously, i.e.,
while the application is processing a buffer, the acquisition of the next buffer is done
in parallel.

The CInstantCamera class uses a pool of buffers to retrieve image data
from the camera device. Once a buffer is filled and ready,
the buffer can be retrieved from the camera object for processing. The buffer
and additional image data are collected in a grab result. The grab result is
held by a smart pointer after retrieval. The buffer is automatically reused
when explicitly released or when the smart pointer object is destroyed.
*/

#include <pylon/PylonIncludes.h>
#ifdef PYLON_WIN_BUILD
#include <pylon/PylonGUI.h>
#endif

#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"


  using namespace cv;

  // Namespace for using pylon objects.
  using namespace Pylon;


  // Namespace for using cout.
  using namespace std;

// Number of images to be grabbed.
static const uint32_t c_countOfImagesToGrab = 100;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
// The exit code of the sample application.
int exitCode = 0;

// Automagically call PylonInitialize and PylonTerminate to ensure 
// the pylon runtime system is initialized during the lifetime of this object.
Pylon::PylonAutoInitTerm autoInitTerm;


CGrabResultPtr ptrGrabResult;
namedWindow("CV_Image",WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
try
{

    CInstantCamera camera( CTlFactory::GetInstance().CreateFirstDevice());
    cout << "Using device " << camera.GetDeviceInfo().GetModelName() << endl;
     camera.Open();

    GenApi::CIntegerPtr width(camera.GetNodeMap().GetNode("Width"));
     GenApi::CIntegerPtr height(camera.GetNodeMap().GetNode("Height"));
     Mat cv_img(width->GetValue(), height->GetValue(), CV_8UC3);

    camera.StartGrabbing();
    CPylonImage image;
    CImageFormatConverter fc;
     fc.OutputPixelFormat = PixelType_RGB8packed;

    while(camera.IsGrabbing()){
        camera.RetrieveResult( 5000, ptrGrabResult, TimeoutHandling_ThrowException);
        if (ptrGrabResult->GrabSucceeded()){
                 fc.Convert(image, ptrGrabResult);

                cv_img = cv::Mat(ptrGrabResult->GetHeight(),     ptrGrabResult->GetWidth(), CV_8UC3,(uint8_t*)image.GetBuffer());
                imshow("CV_Image",cv_img);
                  waitKey(1);
                if(waitKey(30)==27){
                      camera.StopGrabbing();
                }
        }
    }

}

catch (GenICam::GenericException &e)
{
    // Error handling.
    cerr << "An exception occurred." << endl
    << e.GetDescription() << endl;
    exitCode = 1;
}

// Comment the following two lines to disable waiting on exit
cerr << endl << "Press Enter to exit." << endl;
while( cin.get() != '\n');

return exitCode;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

take the grab.cpp sample code and add following code into the garb.cpp and it will work.

```
CImageFormatConverter fc;

fc.OutputPixelFormat = PixelType_BGR8packed;

CPylonImage image;

if (ptrGrabResult->GrabSucceeded())
{
 fc.Convert(image, ptrGrabResult);
 Mat cv_img = cv::Mat(ptrGrabResult->GetHeight(), ptrGrabResult->GetWidth(), CV_8UC3,    (uint8_t*)image.GetBuffer());
 imshow(src_window,cv_img);  
 waitKey(1);
 }
```