# Convert images from OpenCV to Pylon in C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a Basler camera and a C++ program that captures an image on Pylon format then I convert it to Mat in order to be processed and I want to convert the image again to Pylon format to be display it. I need to do this second convertion because my software works at 150 fps and the function ShowImage from Opencv cant display at that velocity.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what the heck is _Pylon_?

Comment: Pylon is a library developed by the camera brand Basler, and they has their own image format: Pylon Image.

Comment: A simple Google search yielded [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43695811/4962554) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24101877/4962554)

Comment: Thank you for the interest @eshirima  but that dont answer my question, because that is only for convert a pylon type image to Mat format, but I need the opposite conversion.